# Calling a separate object as the context for a Handlebars Partial

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

So I have a HBS template that I am rendering using a backbone model. I want to create a set of partials for UI components that I can call with a different object to generate markup so:

```
<div class="device">
  This is my device default name: {{ defaultName }} <br/>
  This is my device current state: {{ currentState }} <br/>
  This is my device last state: {{ lastState }}
    {{> options}}
</div>
```

and the partial is:

```
{{#each options}}
<span data-value="{{value}}">Label: </span>{{label}} <br/>
{{/each}}
```

I want everything in the main template to use the model as the context and the partial to use a different object that I create in my view. Im trying to avoid having these options be married to my model code, yuck.

**Update**
I did a little work around which is *okay* with $.extend

```
var data = $.extend({}, this.model.toJSON(), this.uiOptions);
this.$el.html(this.template(data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the neatest ways to do this is to have two top level objects and to use the `with` helper in the first template

```
Handlebars.compile(templateFile)({model:modelObj,other:OtherObj})
```

and the template

```
<div class="device">
    {{#with model}}
    This is my device default name: {{ defaultName }} <br/>
    This is my device current state: {{ currentState }} <br/>
    This is my device last state: {{ lastState }}
    {{/with}}
    {{#with other}}
    {{> options}}
    {{/with}}
</div>
```

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you!